# PL/SQL FOR RETURN 질문

Tags: sql, plsql

```
declare
v_sum number(15,2);
begin
for i in 1..100 Loop
v_sum := v_sum + i;
if i = 50 then
RETURN;
end if;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(v_sum);
end;
/
```

If you meet RETURN, you should stop FOR and print dbms_output_line (v_sum);
The output text is not executed.
dbms_output.put_line ('abc'); Even if I put it under, it doesn't print.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

You should read the Oracle PL/SQL documentation.

1. You need to initialize variable `v_sum`.
2. To break out of a loop in PL/SQL use `exit` and not `return`.
3. `dbms_output.put_line()` works on VARCHAR and not NUMBER so use `to_char()` to convert it.
4. If you are using *SQL*Plus* make sure to `set serveroutput on`

I believe the below code does what you want.

```sql
declare
  v_sum number(15,2);
begin
  v_sum := 0;
  for i in 1..100 Loop
    v_sum := v_sum + i;
    if i = 50 then
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('v_sum = ' || to_char(v_sum));
end;
```

Comment: Thank you.
The initial value is assigned to 0
Another number output statement that does not use return was a problem because it works properly without using To_Char.
It uses the exit rather than the return, so it prints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the dbms_output statement will work without you using to_char. It uses implicit conversion rather than explicit conversion. That is a bad habit to get into. For implicit Oracle guesses what the result should be; it is **not a good guesser**. Relying on implicit conversion leads to extremely hard to find bugs hen it guesses wrong. Get out of the implicit conversion habit. Just google "Oracle implicit conversion".  
  
While at it why are you using an IF statement to exit your loop.  A for loop, as used, is at its basic a 'promise' execute the encloses statement a certain number of times. Your IF by design breaks this promise. Yes there are rare exceptions for exiting, but NOT by design. This exit by design makes your code longer and more error prone. That after all is the cause of the question. You want to execute that loop 50 times write it that way:

```
declare
  v_sum number(15,2);
begin
  v_sum := 0;
  for i in 1..50 Loop
    v_sum := v_sum + i;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line('v_sum = ' || to_char(v_sum));
end;
```

or with a little math just

```
declare
  v_num integer := 50
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('sum(1..50) = ' || to_char(n*(n+1)/2));
end;
```